# Looking for a postgres SQL JOIN that gives me a full list of combines rows from two tables, filling in NULL columns where needed

Tags: sql, postgresql

Say there are these tables:

```
product
-----
id
product_name

leads
-----
id
product_id
customer_name

sales
-----
id
product_id
lead_id <- can be null
sales_amount
```

Not all sales will come from a lead.
Not all leads will have any sales.

I want a list of all combined sales and leads together.

Something like:
given a product_id = 7

Give me all sales and leads for product_id 7

```
product_id lead_id sale_id
---------- ------- -------
7             101    501
7             102   NULL
7            NULL    502
```

I tried a select on leads with a FULL OUTER JOIN and a WHERE below

```
FULL OUTER JOIN on sales ON leads.id = sales.lead_id
WHERE clause product_id=7 and leads.product_id=sales.product_id,
```

but I got fewer results than were in the leads or sales tables.

Hope that's clear enough.

Thanks in advance

Comment: [Edit] the question and provide a [example], i.e. the `CREATE` statements of the tables or other objects involved (paste the **text**, don't use images, don't link to external sites), `INSERT` statements for sample data (dito) and the desired result with that sample data in tabular text format. Show a **complete** example query and the given tables or other objects.

Comment: Move the WHERE clause conditions to the ON clause, and see what happens.

Comment: What jarlh means: your WHERE clause turns the outer join back into an inner join

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want the union of two different queries.

I tried to simulate the all the tables below are the screenshots:

**Sales**
[image]

**Leads**
[image]

**Product**
[image]

You can use union operator to join outcomes of two different queries. In this case query will be :

```
select leads.product_id as product_id,leads.id as leads_id,sales_id from leads left join sales  on  sales.lead_id=leads.id and sales.product_id=leads.product_id UNION select sales.product_id as product_id,sales.lead_id as leads_id,sales_id from sales left join leads on sales.lead_id=leads.id and sales.product_id=leads.product_id
```

This will give the expected result :
[image]

Comment: Please don't use images, just plain text. That makes it possible to copy examples and use in another database.

Comment: @codestorm Welcome!
Do not forget to upvote.

Answer (score 0):

If you `UNION ALL` the sales with the leads that have no sales, then you get both.

**Sample data**

> ```
> create table product (
>  id serial primary key, 
>  product_name varchar(30) not null
> );
>
> insert into product (product_name) values 
>   ('apple'), ('egg'), ('bacon')
> , ('milk'), ('carrot'), ('tomato')
> , ('cheese'), ('bean'), ('grape')
> ;
>
> create table leads (
>  id int primary key,
>  product_id int not null, 
>  customer_name varchar(30) not null, 
>  foreign key (product_id) references product(id)
> );
>
> insert into leads (id, product_id, customer_name) values
>   (101, 7, 'john doe')
> , (102, 7, 'jane doe')
> , (103, 1, 'bob modest')
> ;
>
> create table sales (
>  id int primary key,
>  product_id int not null, 
>  lead_id int, 
>  sales_amount decimal(10,2), 
>  foreign key (product_id) references product(id), 
>  foreign key (lead_id) references leads(id)
> );
>
> insert into sales (id, product_id, lead_id, sales_amount) values
>   (501, 7, 101, 12)
> , (502, 7, null,  4)
> ;
> ```

**Query**

> ```
> with cte_products as (
>   select id as product_id
>   from product
>   where product_name = 'cheese'
> )
> select product_id, lead_id, sale_id
> from
> (
>   -- sales with or without leads
>   select 
>     sale.product_id
>   , sale.lead_id
>   , sale.id as sale_id
>   from sales as sale
>   join cte_products using (product_id)
>   
>   union all
>
>   -- leads without sales
>   select 
>     lead.product_id
>   , lead.id as lead_id
>   , null as sale_id
>   from leads as lead
>   join cte_products using (product_id)
>   where not exists (
>       select 1 
>       from sales sale
>       where sale.product_id = lead.product_id
>         and sale.lead_id = lead.id
>     )
> ) q
> ```

But `FULL JOIN` also works

> ```
> with cte_products as (
>   select id as product_id
>   from product
>   where product_name = 'cheese'
> )
> select product_id, lead_id, sale_id
> from
> (
>   select 
>     coalesce(sale.product_id, lead.product_id) as product_id
>   , lead.id as lead_id
>   , sale.id as sale_id
>   from sales as sale
>   full join leads as lead 
>     on lead.id = sale.lead_id
>   join cte_products cte 
>     on cte.product_id in (sale.product_id, lead.product_id)
> ) q;
> ```

| product_id | lead_id | sale_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 7 | 101 | 501 |
| 7 | *null* | 502 |
| 7 | 102 | *null* |

Demo on *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=dbe6eebeee2509db682e49711f97df49)*